# Upload files in Symfony without Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

In Symfony controller I can:

```
$file = $request->files->get('file');
```

If all is good then I don't have problems, but what if uploads return errors?

For example if I send to large file then $file is null, but if I use clear PHP:

```
$_FILES['file']['error']
```

Then I have error. This is good, but how can I do in Symfony?

```
$request->files->get('file')->getError();
```

It is not working because `$request->files->get('file')` is null.

Is it possible to handle errors with `$request->files` in Symfony?

Comment: You should add a validation and try to catch errors there.

Comment: You can assert the input in the entity 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html